# "Simulate" mutations in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

```
import { remoteSettings } from 'somewhere';

const store = {
    state: {
        view: {
            foo: true
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        toggleFoo(state) {
            state.view.foo = !state.view.foo;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async toggleFoo({ state, commit }) {
            commit('toggleFoo');
            await remoteSettings.save(state);
        }
    }
};
```

Say I have a simple store like this. `toggleFoo` action applies the mutation, then saves the new state by making an async call. However, if `remoteSettings.save()` call fails, local setting I have in the store and remote settings are out of sync. What I really want to achieve in this action is something like this:

```
async toggleFoo({ state, commit }) {
    const newState = simulateCommit('toggleFoo');
    await remoteSettings.save(newState);
    commit('toggleFoo');
}
```

I'd like to get the new state without actually committing it. If remote call succeeds, then I'll actually update the store. If not, it's going to stay as it is.

What's the best way to achieve this (without actually duplicating the logic in the mutation function)? Maybe "undo"? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing code from @VamsiKrishna (thank you), I suggest an alternative. In my opinion, you want to send the changes to the server, and update the local state on success. Here is a working example.

To prevent duplicating logic, abstract the change into a function.

```js
console.clear()

const remoteSettings = {
  save(state){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject("Server rejected the update!"), 1000))
  }
}

function updateFoo(state){
  state.view.foo = !state.view.foo
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    view: {
      foo: true
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleFoo(state) {
      updateFoo(state)
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async toggleFoo({ state, commit }) {
      // Make a copy of the state. This simply uses JSON stringify/parse
      // but any technique/library for deep copy will do. Honestly, I don't
      // think you would be sending the *entire* state, but rather only
      // what you want to change
      const oldState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state))
      // update the copy
      updateFoo(oldState)
      try {
        // Attempt to save
        await remoteSettings.save(oldState);
        // Only commit locally if the server OKs the change
        commit('toggleFoo');
      } catch(err) {
        // Otherwise, notify the user the change wasn't allowed
        console.log("Notify the user in some way that the update failed", err)
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  computed:{
    foo(){
      return this.$store.state.view.foo
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    setTimeout(() => this.$store.dispatch("toggleFoo"), 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h4>This value never changes, because the server rejects the change</h4>
  {{foo}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both. I have something like this for now. This looks better to me rather then applying the changes and then undoing them on fail.

I was just wondering if there is a suggested way/best practice/shorthand for such cases in vuex, since I have started playing with it fairly recently.

Answer (score 4):

One way of doing this would be: (credit to **@Bert** for correcting mistakes)

1. Store the old state using `const oldState = state;` before committing the mutation.
2. Wrap the async call in a `try-catch` block.
3. If the `remoteSettings` fails it will pass the execution to `catch` block.
4. In the catch block commit a mutation to reset the state.

Example:

```
const store = {
  state: {
    view: {
      foo: true
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleFoo(state) {
      state.view.foo = !state.view.foo;
    },
    resetState(state, oldState){
      //state = oldState; do not do this

       //use store's instance method replaceState method to replace rootState
        //see :   https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html
      this.replaceState(oldState)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async toggleFoo({ state, commit }) {
      const oldState =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));  //making a deep copy of the state object
      commit('toggleFoo');
      try {
        await remoteSettings.save(newState);
        //commit('toggleFoo'); no need to call this since mutation already commited
      } catch(err) {
        //remoteSettings failed
        commit('resetState', oldState)
      }
    }

  }
};
```

Comment: This is a little backwards from the typical flow. Make the async call, then commit on success. That way there is no need to revert to a different state (which may result in odd behavior in the UI).

Comment: @Bert yup,this is backwards but he wanted to send the mutated state in async call, that's why committed the mutation before the async call.

Comment: Then you should send and updated copy of the state. This doesn't even actually work. Setting `oldState = state` makes a copy by reference and when you try to revert, you just set the state equal to itself.  https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wPVVyO?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert thank you for pointing it out...i updated the answer. You are really good:)

Comment: That doesn't work either. Object spread will make a shallow copy.

Comment: I added comments in the link above that show something that does work. And this is a link to how I think it should be done. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/wPVVRL?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert you modified the old state object using `oldState.view.foo = !oldState.view.foo` ... but if there were more properties changing all of them would be cumbersome right?

Comment: Well, this is the `toggleFoo` action. I'm not sure why it would do a whole bunch of other things.

Comment: True, but neither do I think you would really send the entire state to set one setting. In either case, an action is specific. You want to do one thing. You tell the server what you want to do, then, if the server OKs it you update the local state.

Comment: @Bert yup could be...please update my answer or add new answer:)

Comment: Go ahead and update yours with a working version. I'll post my suggestion as an alternative. Ultimately some of this is opinion.

Comment: There's one more thing; replacing `state` like this `state = oldState` doesn't work either. You need to use `replaceState`, which is [documented in the API](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html). I show that in the comments of the first link above as well.